# Assigning an item to an existing array in a list within a dictionary

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary, unityscript

I have a Dictionary in UnityScript declared like:

```
public var PoolDict : Dictionary.<String, List.<GameObject[]> >;
```

If I want to add items to an **existing** array in the list, how could it be written?

Here was my initial attempt, which produces an error.

```
    PoolDict[key][0].Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code is attempting to call a method declared in list on an array. `PoolDict`. This is because `PoolDict[key]` returns a list, and `PoolDict[key][0]` returns a `GameObject[]`. `Add()` is not a function defined in arrays, so you can either change `Add()` to `push()`, or change the initial constructor of `PoolDict` to be a `Dictionary<string, List<List<GameObject>>>`